# What affects the flight of rockets?

Tags: rockets, experiment, science

I need some help on my science experiment. I have tried researching it on the internet but nothing seemed to have answered my question. I am currently doing a science fair project on "How does Rocket Fuel affect Rockets". By that I mean any variables such air resistance, weight, drag, thrust,and lift. I'm wondering if I use different rocket fuels, if it will have an impact on the previous variables. I  am more than happy to receive any information regarding rockets.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What kinds of effects are you looking for?

Comment: You can [start here](https://spaceflightsystems.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/bgmr.html) or go to [the index](https://spaceflightsystems.grc.nasa.gov/education/rocket/shortr.html), which for some reason is [also here](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/rocket/shortr.html). I found a link to [How Rockets Work](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/153415main_Rockets_How_Rockets_Work.pdf) for example at NASA's [Rockets Educator Guide](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/topnav/materials/listbytype/Rockets.html).

Comment: The variables you should be looking at are thrust, specific impulse and delta-V. The research of rocket fuels is finding the precarious balance between highest energy density possible while retaining modicum of stability - most of extremely energetic substances are extremely unstable, exploding at smallest provocation (or even without).

Answer (score 2):

The choice of rocket fuels directly affect the weight of a rocket, due to the difference in efficiency, measured in [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse).

Depending on the choice of fuel, the size of engine will change to produce the required thrust - this will affect the weight, and potentially the aerodynamic cross-section of the vehicle, which will affect the lift and drag.

The choice of fuel will affect the size of the storage tanks, and what they are made of, and whether then need insulation - this will affect the weight and aerodynamic properties of the vehicle, in turn affecting the lift and drag.

Answer (score 1):

This question has massive scope, but it is clear that the OP is at a very novice level, so i will attempt answer at this level.

The typical way rocket fuels are compared is by considering their *specific impulse*.  Different propellant/oxidizer combos only offer a certain amount of specific impulse, which ultimately affects the maximum possible velocity achievable. In general, solid propellants have lower specific impulse than liquid propellants.  However, liquid propellants are more complicated to create (pumps, cooling, slosh control, etc.) which adds weight and complexity to the overall system compared to solid propellant systems.

You may want to look at Tsiolkovsky’s rocket equation for a simple estimate of how propellant mass and specific impulse can be used to estimate the maximum velocity acheivable for a given rocket (ignoring drag & gravity losses).